# Automating import of an Excel file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to import a file, saved in our public drive, into an Access database as a table.

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim TimeStamp2 As String
TimeStamp2 = Month(Date) & "." & Day(Date) - 1 & "." & Year(Date)
Dim xlFile As String, shtName
xlFile = "Open Orders @ " & TimeStamp2 & ".xls"
shtName = "Current Open Orders"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet aclimport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Open Orders From Yesterday", "\\cletus\KNXGENDB$\Daily Order Bookings\Open Orders @ " & TimeStamp2 & ".xls", True, shtName & "!"
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Run time error 2306: There are too many rows to output, based on the limitation specified by the output format or by Microsoft Access

Comment: Check the format of the document - in your `xFile` variable you use ".xlsx" and in your `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` function call, you use ".xls". Do you get any specific error message when you run your code?

Comment: I changed that, thanks for pointing it out! The error I get now is "Run time error 2306: There are too many rows to output, based on the limitation specified by the output format or by Microsoft Access."

Comment: Can you add that into your question below the code? You can use double asterisks to bold it `**like this**` = **like this**. It will be very useful for anyone with the same problem who googles that error number. It will also help anyone coming here to answer the question :)

Comment: Ok, one more thing: in your `DoCmd`, you have "aclimport", but the actual spelling is "acImport" (no "l")

Comment: So I think I realize why I'm getting this; it's literally how it sounds, I'm trying to output too many rows. However, the file is supposed to be much much smaller.. I found that the reason is because the file I'm importing is being exploded into a massive, duplicated file when it imports, although it's supposed to be much smaller as well.. So I think there's a problem with importing the table. Could it be that I'm doing the TimeStamp wrong- is there another way to say "Yesterday"? Or is it something else? Again, stumped.

Comment: Lucky - what's happening is the misspelled `acImport` constant. Because you misspelled it, VBA doesn't recognize it, so it automatically treats it as a new variable with a value of 0.  Unfortunately for you, the transfer type of 0 is actually **acExport**! So this code actually tries to export the table to Excel instead of importing.

Comment: To fix it, correct the spelling of `acImport`

Comment: Alright I figured out what the issue is. It looks like whenever I run the query, it's appending to the table, not replacing over it. How do I put in the code for the import to replace the table, not add to it? I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: Would I do something like "CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM Open Orders From Yesterday" ? I say "something like" because I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Try `DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Open Orders From Yesterday"`

Comment: Thanks Blackhawk!! That worked, finally finished. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Lucky - if the suggestions worked for you, go ahead and accept the answer I posted by clicking the green checkmark next to it. I put all the information from the comments into the answer so anyone with the same problem can find it all in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the specific fixes:

1. Fix the file extension. In one place you have it as ".xlsx" and in another, ".xls"
2. Correct the spelling of `acImport` (in your code it is incorrectly spelled as "aclImport")
3. To delete the table before you import, try `DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Open Orders From Yesterday"`
4. When dimensioning multiple variables on the same line, you have to provide a variable type for each or it will use the default of Variant. So in this case you would write `Dim xFile As String, shtName As String`
5. You don't actually use the `xFile` variable. You should either remove it or add it into the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` line to avoid confusion.

And here is everything all together:

```
Dim TimeStamp2 As String
TimeStamp2 = Month(Date) & "." & Day(Date) - 1 & "." & Year(Date)
Dim shtName As String
shtName = "Current Open Orders"

'Delete the existing table
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Open Orders From Yesterday"

'Import the data, recreating the table
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet aclimport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Open Orders From Yesterday", "\\cletus\KNXGENDB$\Daily Order Bookings\Open Orders @ " & TimeStamp2 & ".xls", True, shtName & "!"
```

---

One question: is your sheet name really "Current Open Orders!"? If not, you probably want to remove the exclamation mark from the end of `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet aclimport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Open Orders From Yesterday", "\\cletus\KNXGENDB$\Daily Order Bookings\Open Orders @ " & TimeStamp2 & ".xls", True, shtName & "!"`

Answer (score 0):

Try dimming "Open Orders from Yesterday" and the file path, etc.

This code worked for me to do the same thing.  You can ignore the loop if it's only one file you're doing.

```
Sub Import2()

    Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
    Dim strWorksheet As String, strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

    ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
    ' has field names
    blnHasFieldNames = True

    ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
    ' contains the EXCEL files
    strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Folder\"

    ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
    ' the data are to be imported
    strTable = "AccessTableNameGoesHere"

    strWorksheet = "DataSheet"

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
          strPathFile = strPath & strFile
          DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, strWorksheet & "$"

    ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
    ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
    '       Kill strPathFile

          strFile = Dir()
    Loop

    MsgBox "Import Successful!"

End Sub
```